# Customizing "grid" Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, grid, tailwind-css

I'm struggled with customizing Tailwind CSS. 
How do I customize the code below?
Any help is appreciated!

```
grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<h2 class="text-purple-600 grid grid-cols-3"><span>1</span><span class="col-span-2">2</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the ideas from your code and actually learned alot today on document.